# How do I build a directive in angular that adds a wrapper around an input and shows message if input is invalid?

Tags: angularjs

I'm a  total beginner in Angular, so maybe I am thinking about it totally wrong.

What I'm trying to do is create a directive that wraps an input in some boilerplate html. It should bind the input's ng-model to the parent scope (the `myForm` controller's scope) but should have access to the validation state of the input.

Here's my setup:

`parent_form.html`

```
<form name="myForm">
  <div fieldContainer label="'Field 1'" model="'field1'">
    <input type="text" ng-model="field1" required/>
  </div>
  <div fieldContainer label="'Field 2'" model="'field2'">
    <input type="text" ng-model="field2" required/>
  </div>
</form>
```

`field_container.html`

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-5">{{label}}</div>
   <div class="col-md-5" ng-transclude></div>
   <div class="col-md-2" ng-show="valid">REQUIRED!</div>
</div>
```

`parent_form.js`

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('myForm', function ($scope) {
     $scope.field1 = '';
     $scope.field2 = '';
  })
  .directive('fieldContainer', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      templateUrl: 'field_container.html',
      transclude: true,
      scope: {
        label: '=label',
        model : '=model'
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: you are doing it wrong. For validation I recommend the following post: http://www.yearofmoo.com/2014/09/taming-forms-in-angularjs-1-3.html

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by:

- Adding a name to the field (so that Angular's Form validation takes over)
- Setting `ng-show` on the validation message to be: `$parent.myForm[model].$valid`

So apparently the transcluded input still uses the parent (`myForm`) scope and the directive has access to the parent's scope via `scope.$parent`.

Not sure if this is the cleanest way to do it...

Final code looks like:

`parent_form.html`

```
<form name="myForm">
  <div fieldContainer label="'Field 1'" model="'field1'">
    <input type="text" name="field1" ng-model="field1" required/>
  </div>
  <div fieldContainer label="'Field 2'" model="'field2'">
    <input type="text" name="field2" ng-model="field2" required/>
  </div>
</form>
```

`field_container.html`

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-5">{{label}}</div>
   <div class="col-md-5" ng-transclude></div>
   <div class="col-md-2" ng-show="$parent.myForm[model].$valid">REQUIRED!</div>
</div>
```